# Proving that $\exp\in H(\mathbb{C})$ and calculating its derivative

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, exponential-function

Let's define $\exp(z)$ in the following form:
$$\exp(z) = \sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n!}, z \in \mathbb{C} \tag{1}$$
We know that the definition above stands (I mean that the series converges).
We are to prove that $z\mapsto \exp(z)$ is a holomorphic function over $\mathbb{C}$.

---

Firstly I would like to prove that $\exp \in H(\mathbb{C})$.
I know that $f(z)=z$ is a holomorphic function (I've proven it using Cauchy-Riemann's equations).
It is obvious that $\forall_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ $f_n(z) = \frac{z}{n}$ is holomorphic (is it?).
If the statement above stands it would be good to say that an infinite sum of holomorphic functions is holomorphic. I'm not sure it it's true however.

---

Secondly let's calculate $\frac{\mbox{d}}{\mbox{dz}}\exp(z)$.
Because we know that $z\mapsto \exp(z)$ is holomorphic (to my mind it basically means that I can calculate this derivative using methods from real analysis, am I correct?) and the series converges we can calculate it in the following form (using $(1)$):
$$\frac{\mbox{d}}{\mbox{dz}}\exp(z) =\frac{\mbox{d}}{\mbox{dz}} \sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n!} = \sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\mbox{d}}{\mbox{dz}}\frac{z^n}{n!} = \sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} n \frac{z^{n-1}}{n!} = \sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} = \sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^{n}}{n!} = \exp(z)$$Is it calculated well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must know that every analytic function (i.e. which can be written as the sum of a power series, like $\exp$) is holomorphic.

Moreover, if you recall the theorem saying that it's possible to exchange $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}$ and $\dfrac{d}{dz}$ in the case of power series, then your computation is correct.

In any case, be careful to check first the radius of convergence of the power series. Here, using ratio test:

$$\dfrac{\dfrac{z^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}}{\dfrac{z^{n}}{n!}} = \dfrac{z}{n+1}$$

goes to $0$ when $n$ go to $+\infty$, thus it's convergent on $\Bbb C$.

Comment: Thank you! So using the theorem that every analytical function is holomorphic we get the thesis immediately from the definition of $\exp(z)$?

Comment: That's exactly my point.

Comment: Thank you! :) And yes, you are right with the radius of convergence. But in this case it was written in my task that the radius in infinite thus in is convergent on $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: One more question - the holomorphism of $\sin$ and $\cos$ is obvious because they are sum of $\exp(iz)$ and $\exp(-iz)$ which are holomorphic?

Comment: Linear combination but yes, it's correct.

Comment: Thank you, now I understand it! :)